# ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback is not invoked when using Polly

Tags: c#, .net, polly

I'm using Polly to send https requests to an external server, the problem is the `ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback` is never invoked:

```
public class CustomeHttpClient : HttpClientHandler {
 ...
 ...
 protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) {

  ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (requestMessage, certificate, chain, sslError) =>
  {
    // custome validations
  };
   return await Policy
               .Handle<Exception>()
               .WaitAndRetryAsync(_retryPolicy.RetryCount,
                                  retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(_retryPolicy.MillisecondsBeforeRetry),
                                  (ex, t, retryCount, ctx) => _logger.LogWarning("Retry attempt SendAsync {OutgoingRequestUri}", request.RequestUri))
               .ExecuteAsync(async () => 
               {
                   return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
               });
 }
}
```

the `ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback` callback is invoked only when I send request without Polly,
Any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: I don't think it is directly related to your problem but the proper way to pass `CancellationToken` to the `ExecuteAsync` is the following: `.ExecuteAsync(async (ct) => await base.SendAsync(request, ct), cancellationToken); `.

Comment: Btw are you aware of the fact that a HttpRequestMessage instance can't be reused? When you want to use it for the second time HttpClient will throw an InvalidOperationException.

Comment: Hi thanks, when I changed the CancellationToken nothing happened, same as before the callback does not trigger

Comment: Are you sure that the retry policy is triggered?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried to use your `HttpClientHandler`, works totally fine:

```
var t1 = Task.Run(async () =>
{
    var cl = new HttpClient(new CustomeHttpClient());
    var msg = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://www.google.com");

    var response = await cl.SendAsync(msg);
});
```

A Breakpoint inside your `ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback` is hit as expected while using a Polly policy.

```
public class CustomeHttpClient : HttpClientHandler
{

     protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     {

        ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (requestMessage, certificate, chain, sslError) =>
        {
            // a breakpoint here is hit as expected
            return true;
        };

        return await Policy...
```

Maybe you never actually use your `CustomeHttpClient`?